# Make Nginx point to vhost when visiting server via its IP address

Tags: domain-name-system, nginx, virtualhost

I have a newly set up VPS running Nginx on Ubuntu.

Currently when I visit my server's IP (e.g. `http://123.123.123.123`) it shows the contents of `/usr/share/nginx/www`.

My only vhost (`mydomain.com`) is in `/srv/www/mydomain.com/public_html`

The actual domain is not pointed to my VPS yet as it is still being used on a production site. How do I access the vhost through my VPS's IP without editing the domain DNS settings? Basically when I type my VPS IP address in a browser it should take me to the site in my vhost.

Ideally I would like a config so that I can just change the A record on `mydomain.com` when the time comes and it will go from serving it's current site to pointing to the site on my VPS.

Answer (score 0):

There will be a default vhost which has `/usr/share/nginx/www` set as the `root`. You probably want to disable this vhost so it only uses the vhost for your domain.

Comment: OK, I've done this by removing the `default` symlink in sites-enabled. Now when I visit the server's IP it redirects to mydomain.com taking me to the production site, not the site on the vhost